# Transformar atributos de JSON en ejes de un matriz

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy consumiendo un JSON para realizar un grafico con Chartjs de tipo barras de estilo stacked, los atributos de JSON los estoy tratando de transformar en los ejes una matriz, y después alimentar el grafico con esa matriz, pero los datos que refleja la matriz no están siendo fieles a la información entregada por el JSON

El Json que consumo es de este estilo:

```
[
    {
        "parte": "Soket Bolt 5x7",
        "defecto": "Razguño ligero",
        "total": 3
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT LNG",
        "defecto": "Sin recubrimiento",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT L Console",
        "defecto": "Roto",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Pegamento con contaminación",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "parte": "DrainBoxL",
        "defecto": "Fuera de especificación",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "Cushion Fr Frame",
        "defecto": "Sin collar",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "Cushion Fr Frame",
        "defecto": "Otros",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT Sunshade",
        "defecto": "Roto",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT Sunshade",
        "defecto": "Rayado",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Side",
        "defecto": "Aplicación de primer NG",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Sin recubrimiento",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Sin pegamento",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Mal ensamblado",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "Blade Deflector",
        "defecto": "Deforme",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT LNG",
        "defecto": "Sin incerto metalico",
        "total": 1
    }
]
```

En 2 arreglos diferentes, obtengo las partes y defectos sin repetirse:

```
let partes = [];
let defectos = [];
topcorrection.forEach(e => { if (!partes.includes(e.parte)) { partes.push(e.parte); } });
topcorrection.forEach(e => { if (!defectos.includes(e.defecto)) { defectos.push(e.defecto) } });
```

Definí otro arreglo `datamatrix` para almacenar los valores de total en forma de matriz, para hacerlo utilice 3 ciclos

```
let datamatrix = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < defectos.length; i++)
            {
                let datamatrix_x = [];
                for (let j = 0; j < partes.length; j++) {
                    for (let z = 0; z < topcorrection.length; z++)
                    {
                        if (((defectos[i] === topcorrection[z].defecto) && (partes[j] === topcorrection[z].parte)))
                        {
                            datamatrix_x.push(topcorrection[z].total);
                        }
                    }
                    datamatrix_x.push(0);
                }
                datamatrix.push(datamatrix_x);
            }
```

Pero la salida que estoy esperando es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La salida que obtengo es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para poder graficar con Chartjs este grafico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los datos de la matriz resultante no son los mismos que la matriz esperada, no alcanzo a ver porque sale una columna 9 y una columna 10. O si hay otra forma de dejarle la tarea a chart

Answer (score 1):

Para generar esa matriz tienes que hacer algo como esto:

```
class Defecto {
    constructor(nombre,partes) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        for (let p of partes) {
            this[p] = 0;
        }
    }
    add(parte, valor) {
        this[parte] += valor;
    }
}
const Partes = Array.from(new Set(lista.map(x => x.parte)));
const MATRIX = []
for (let item of lista) {
    let d = new Defecto(item.defecto, Partes);
    d.add(item.parte, item.total);
    MATRIX.push(d);
}
console.table(MATRIX);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a mí me parece que quieres otra cosa, que es un array de array, entonces debería ser:

```js
const lista=[
    {
        "parte": "Soket Bolt 5x7",
        "defecto": "Razguño ligero",
        "total": 3
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT LNG",
        "defecto": "Sin recubrimiento",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT L Console",
        "defecto": "Roto",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Pegamento con contaminación",
        "total": 2
    },
    {
        "parte": "DrainBoxL",
        "defecto": "Fuera de especificación",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "Cushion Fr Frame",
        "defecto": "Sin collar",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "Cushion Fr Frame",
        "defecto": "Otros",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT Sunshade",
        "defecto": "Roto",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT Sunshade",
        "defecto": "Rayado",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Side",
        "defecto": "Aplicación de primer NG",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Sin recubrimiento",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Sin pegamento",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT R Console",
        "defecto": "Mal ensamblado",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "Blade Deflector",
        "defecto": "Deforme",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "parte": "BRKT LNG",
        "defecto": "Sin incerto metalico",
        "total": 1
    }
];

//Lista de partes no repetidas
const Partes = Array.from(new Set(lista.map(x => x.parte)));

let MATRIX = []
for (let item of lista) {
    let parts = [];
    for(let p of Partes){
      if(p == item.parte){
        parts.push(item.total);
      }
      else{
        parts.push(0);
      }
    }
    MATRIX.push(parts);
}

console.log(MATRIX);
```

Según lo que veo de tus datos es que la combinación defectos y partes es única. Así que la idea general es obtener la lista de partes, luego recorrer la lista de los daatos. A cada sublista se le agrega cero si el parte no corresponde (una especie de fill), caso contrario se agrega el valor correspondiente

Answer (score 0):

aunque lo mio no es ni por asomo como la respuesta de Yussef ( felicidades ) te dejo mi granito aqui. Espero que te sirva , Saludos !
Cualquier mejora o distinto punto de vista no duden.

```
       let datamatrix = [];
       let a=[]
       let total=[]
       defectos.forEach(e=>{
       let datamatrix_x = [];
          for (let i = 0; i < partes.length; i++){
          let num=0
          let bol=false
          topcorrection.forEach(x=>{
          num++
          if(x.defecto===e && x.parte===partes[i]){
            datamatrix_x.push(x.total)
             bol=true
            }
         })
      if (num==topcorrection.length && bol!=true){
          datamatrix_x.push(0)
         }
      }
       a.push(datamatrix_x)

         })     
    'Summing vertically'    
      const b = a.reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + b[i]));
       a.push(b)
```

[image: ejemplo]

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe en qué consiste _tu granito de arena_. Una respuesta es mucho más útil cuando contiene explicación: puede que para ti sea obvio cómo funciona, pero para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar, no. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: si , tienes razón. Gracias